# I deleted LanmanServer service by mistake how can I install it again?

Tags: windows-7, services

I had problems with LanmanServer and I wanted to kill it and restart it. By mistake I instead deleted it by running this command:

```
sc delete LanmanServer
```

How can I reinstall it? The entry Server disappeared from `services.msc` .

Comment: I have exported the registry entry of my Win7 VM: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qdeuv1mh4gn3b6n/LanmanServer_Win7.reg?dl=0 try to import the reg and look if you can start the service again

Comment: thanks. I imported it. When I write in cmd: "sc start lanmanserver" I get :
[SC] StartService: OpenService ERROR 1060:The specified service is not installed (translated literally from italian). Any clue?

Comment: not really. Run processmonitor to see what else is missing: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-3-Process-Monitor, https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-4-Process-Monitor